# Check if Windsor has a matching component registered

Tags: castle-windsor

In a Castle Windsor scenario I want to check if my container has a certain service registered, and do basically

```
if (container.HasComponentFor<IMyService>()) {
    // resolve service with container.Resolve<IMyService>()
    // then do cool stuff
}
```

but of course, `container.HasComponentFor<IMyService>()` doesn't exist. Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can check if the MicroKernel has the component registered:

```
if (container.Kernel.HasComponent(typeof(IMyService)))
    // resolve service with container.Resolve<IMyService>()
    // then do cool stuff
}
```

Comment: This does seem like the best option. I think I'll write an extension method on `IWindsorContainer` to match the syntax I wanted =)

Comment: @TomasLycken I was trying this piece of code which results in exception
`if(Ioc.Container.Kernel.HasComponent(typeof(myInterface)))
            {
                Ioc.Container.Release(Ioc.Container.Resolve<myInterface>());
Ioc.Container.Register(Component.For<myInterface>().Instance(myObjectInstance).LifeStyle.Transient);
            }`
But when I try to register the component inside the if statement it results in error even though it was already released. It says that the component is already registered. My castle windsor assembly version is 2.5.1

Comment: Release doesn't remove the component from the container. If you need to add a new component that overrides the existing one, you just need to add it with "IsDefault()", i.e. `if(Ioc.Container.Kernel.HasComponent(typeof(myInterface)))
{
 Ioc.Container.Register(Component.For<myInterface>().Instance(myObjectInstance).IsDefault().L‌​ifeStyle.Transient);
}`

Comment: Note that this doesn't guarantee the `Resolve` call will actually work.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `container.Kernel.HasComponent()`